# SailsJS User create doesn't return

Tags: sails.js, jwt

I'm following this tutorial here:

https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/

I'm running into a problem where the `User.create(...);` line of code doesn't return and so my POSTMAN test times out.

The block of code which I think is causing the problem here is:

```
signup: function(req, res) {
    console.log('\n\nCreating a new user...');

    User
    .create(_.omit(req.allParams(), 'id'))
    .then(function (user) {
        console.log('\n\nreturning newly created user...');

        return {
            // TODO: replace with new type of cipher service
            token: CipherService.createToken(user),
            user: user
        };
    })
    .then(res.created)
    .catch(res.serverError);
},
```

I see the first console output:

```
info: Starting app...

info: 
info:                .-..-.
info: 
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.11.0             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------' 
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: Server lifted in `/Users/MacUser/SailsProjects/myApi`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Sat Sep 12 2015 15:41:21 GMT+0800 (AWST)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------


Creating a new user...
```

But I don't see the second console output =/

Anyone know what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, my bad...seems like I missed a line when following the above tutorial.

I had this in my `User.js` model class:

```
beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    CipherService.hashPassword(values);
}
```

When it should be:

```
beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    CipherService.hashPassword(values);

    next(); // <--- this line was missing

}
```